# Siri not working on iPhone SE, iOS 12.1.4

Tags: iphone, ios, siri, microphone

My siri stopped working completely. It seems like she is not receiving the sound at all. Needless to say, the "Hey, Siri" also doesn't work. since I switched to iPhone SE it stopped working. I hold home button and the waves animation comes on, but it just kind of floats there, without registering anything, and without hearing my words. It works fine on my iPhone 5S, with the same settings of language. I have microphone working fine, I can record crisp sounds, and internet connection on. Things I tried:
-Tried wifi and cellular, and it just doesn't seem to listen.
-I tried to reset the phone - nothing,
-I tried to turn off/turn on Siri in settings - nothing,
-I tried switching on "Hey, Siri" feature, and I can't set it, because Siri - again - cannot hear and sample my voice.
-I tried turning on/off the airplane mode - nothing,
-I tried with turned on low power mode - nothing
-I tried with turned off low power mode - nothing
I really don't know what is happening. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried setting it up again in Settings?

Comment: Yes, I did. I didn't even mention all the things I tried. I willl add to the question.